# Perm and Det mod $2^k$ - II

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, logspace

Given a $0/1$ square matrix, the permanent and determinant modulo $2^k$ is in $\oplus P$ and $\oplus L$ respectively for any fixed $k$. In fact both are in $\oplus L$ (in fact in $\oplus SPACE(k^2\log n)$ by https://mbraverm.princeton.edu/files/planarCounting.pdf.

Suppose we know permanent and determinant mod $2^{k-1}$. Then

1. what is the best complexity class we would be in for each of permanent and determinant modulo $2^k$ when $k=\Omega(\log n)$?
2. What about for permanent and determinant mod $2^{k+r}$ where $r=O(1)$?
3. what is the best time complexity known when $k=\Omega(\log n)$?

Comment: Are you asking: given as input (A,z) where A is an n x n integer matrix and z = det(A) mod 2^{k-1}, compute det(A) mod 2^k? (And similar for perm)

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Yes.